# Modifying the compilation process with SPEC to use LLVM

Tags: benchmarking, llvm, specifications

I am currently working on running some llvm passes and would like to benchmark their usefulness using the SPEC 2006 CPU benchmark suite. However, I've not figured out how to modify the SPEC setup to do anything other than use llvm-gcc to output llvm bitcode. Here is what I'd like to modify the workflow of SPEC to do:

compile the .o files with llvm into llvm-bytecode

```
llvm-gcc -emit-llvm *.c
```

For each .o file, run opt (llvm's optimization pass):

```
opt -adce -mem2reg cfline.o
```

Link with llvm-link:

```
llvm-link *.o -o out.o.linked
```

Turn the llvm bytecode into assembly

```
llc out.o.linked
```

And finally turn that into executable code:

```
gcc out.o.linked -o out.executable
```

Is there a way I can do this? I know I can edit the .cfg files to emit llvm, but then I don't know how to choose a different linking/pre-linking procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: Am kind of stuck in a same situation. I was going through test-suite thing but still no luck. Since this post is too old, I hope that you might have resolved this problem. So can you give me some details on it. I mean how actually you did resolve your problem?

Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM has a [test-suite](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/test-suite/) subproject that already knows how to build and run SPEC. See the [docs](http://llvm.org/docs/TestingGuide.html#testsuiterun) for more info.

Comment: llvm-test-2.9.tgz: llvm-test-2.9/External/SPEC

Answer (score 1):

In CPUSPEC2017, the linker can be modified using the config file. CLD/CXXLD needs to be set. For example,
CLD = $(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-link,
CXXLD = $(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-link.

The opt command can also be run by modifying the Makefile.defaults file. It can be added in the section specifying the commands to build the executables.

Comment: Is there a way to not modify the original file (Makefile.defaults), but define a new file (ex. new-Makefile.defaults) and use it instead? It would be generally more convenient